# tomcat 7 Spring 3.1 Eclipselink 2.3

Tags: spring, jpa, eclipselink, aspectj

I am trying to develop my first spring application and deploy it to tomcat 7. I created the project configuration and every thing was working fine. I faced a problem when I changed a onetoone field fetch mode to LAZY.

I think the problem is with load-time-weaving

following are the configuration:

```
<bean id="scholarDataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="scholarEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="scholarDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="edu.najah.scholar.spring.entities" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle11Platform"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect" />
    </property>        
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="scholarEmf" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="edu.najah.scholar.spring" />
<context:load-time-weaver />
```

and I added the following to META-INF/context.xml

```
<Loader loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader"/>
```

THE FOLLOWING ERROR IS RAISED IN THE FIRST REQUEST:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-60] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The method [_persistence_set_translation_vh] or [_persistence_get_translation_vh] is not defined in the object [edu.najah.scholar.entities.Node].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: edu.najah.scholar.entities.Node._persistence_get_translation_vh()
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping[translation]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(edu.najah.scholar.entities.Node --> [DatabaseTable(SCHOLAR.NODE)])

Exception [EclipseLink-218] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A NullPointerException would have occurred accessing a non-existent weaved _vh_ method [_persistence_get_translation_vh].  The class was not weaved properly - for EE deployments, check the module order in the application.xml deployment descriptor and verify that the module containing the persistence unit is ahead of any other module that uses it.

Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [NODE] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(edu.najah.scholar.entities.Journal --> [DatabaseTable(SCHOLAR.JOURANL)])

Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [NODE] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(edu.najah.scholar.entities.Journal --> [DatabaseTable(SCHOLAR.JOURANL)])

Exception [EclipseLink-41] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(edu.najah.scholar.entities.JournalIssue --> [DatabaseTable(SCHOLAR.NODE), DatabaseTable(SCHOLAR.JOURNAL_ISSUE)])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

java.lang.NullPointerException

    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause 

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-60] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The method [_persistence_set_translation_vh] or [_persistence_get_translation_vh] is not defined in the object [edu.najah.scholar.entities.Node].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: edu.najah.scholar.entities.Node._persistence_get_translation_vh()
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping[translation]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(edu.najah.scholar.entities.Node --> [DatabaseTable(SCHOLAR.NODE)])

Exception [EclipseLink-218] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A NullPointerException would have occurred accessing a non-existent weaved _vh_ method [_persistence_get_translation_vh].  The class was not weaved properly - for EE deployments, check the module order in the application.xml deployment descriptor and verify that the module containing the persistence unit is ahead of any other module that uses it.

Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [NODE] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(edu.najah.scholar.entities.Journal --> [DatabaseTable(SCHOLAR.JOURANL)])

Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [NODE] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(edu.najah.scholar.entities.Journal --> [DatabaseTable(SCHOLAR.JOURANL)])

Exception [EclipseLink-41] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(edu.najah.scholar.entities.JournalIssue --> [DatabaseTable(SCHOLAR.NODE), DatabaseTable(SCHOLAR.JOURNAL_ISSUE)])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

java.lang.NullPointerException

    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:501)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:188)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:277)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:290)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:268)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:517)
    $Proxy33.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:234)
    $Proxy43.find(Unknown Source)
    edu.najah.scholar.spring.dao.NodeDaoImpl.find(NodeDaoImpl.java:43)
    edu.najah.scholar.spring.bo.NodeBoImpl.find(NodeBoImpl.java:38)
    edu.najah.scholar.spring.controller.JounralController.test(JounralController.java:91)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause 

Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-60] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The method [_persistence_set_translation_vh] or [_persistence_get_translation_vh] is not defined in the object [edu.najah.scholar.entities.Node].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: edu.najah.scholar.entities.Node._persistence_get_translation_vh()
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping[translation]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(edu.najah.scholar.entities.Node --> [DatabaseTable(SCHOLAR.NODE)])

Exception [EclipseLink-218] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A NullPointerException would have occurred accessing a non-existent weaved _vh_ method [_persistence_get_translation_vh].  The class was not weaved properly - for EE deployments, check the module order in the application.xml deployment descriptor and verify that the module containing the persistence unit is ahead of any other module that uses it.

Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [NODE] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(edu.najah.scholar.entities.Journal --> [DatabaseTable(SCHOLAR.JOURANL)])

Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [NODE] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(edu.najah.scholar.entities.Journal --> [DatabaseTable(SCHOLAR.JOURANL)])

Exception [EclipseLink-41] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(edu.najah.scholar.entities.JournalIssue --> [DatabaseTable(SCHOLAR.NODE), DatabaseTable(SCHOLAR.JOURNAL_ISSUE)])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

java.lang.NullPointerException

    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:535)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:476)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:435)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:673)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.login(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:631)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:208)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:472)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:188)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:277)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:290)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:268)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:517)
    $Proxy33.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:234)
    $Proxy43.find(Unknown Source)
    edu.najah.scholar.spring.dao.NodeDaoImpl.find(NodeDaoImpl.java:43)
    edu.najah.scholar.spring.bo.NodeBoImpl.find(NodeBoImpl.java:38)
    edu.najah.scholar.spring.controller.JounralController.test(JounralController.java:91)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.22 logs.
```

IN THE NEXT REQUESTS THE FOLLOWING ERROR RAISED:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is Exception [EclipseLink-44] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Missing class indicator field from database row [ArrayRecord(
    SCHOLAR.NODE.ID => 407
    SCHOLAR.NODE.LANG => ar
    SCHOLAR.NODE.OWNER => null
    SCHOLAR.NODE.TRANSLATION_ID => 408)].
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(edu.najah.scholar.entities.Node --> [DatabaseTable(SCHOLAR.NODE)])
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause 

Exception [EclipseLink-44] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Missing class indicator field from database row [ArrayRecord(
    SCHOLAR.NODE.ID => 407
    SCHOLAR.NODE.LANG => ar
    SCHOLAR.NODE.OWNER => null
    SCHOLAR.NODE.TRANSLATION_ID => 408)].
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(edu.najah.scholar.entities.Node --> [DatabaseTable(SCHOLAR.NODE)])
    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException.missingClassIndicatorField(DescriptorException.java:945)
    org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.InheritancePolicy.classFromRow(InheritancePolicy.java:341)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:597)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:568)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:733)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.registerResultInUnitOfWork(ReadObjectQuery.java:774)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadObjectQuery.java:455)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1097)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:829)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1056)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.execute(ReadObjectQuery.java:416)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1144)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2863)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1501)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1483)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1443)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.executeQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:820)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.findInternal(EntityManagerImpl.java:760)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:653)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:532)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365)
    $Proxy43.find(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    $Proxy43.find(Unknown Source)
    edu.najah.scholar.spring.dao.NodeDaoImpl.find(NodeDaoImpl.java:43)
    edu.najah.scholar.spring.bo.NodeBoImpl.find(NodeBoImpl.java:38)
    edu.najah.scholar.spring.controller.JounralController.test(JounralController.java:91)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.22 logs.
```

NOTE: i AM USING A polymorphic query (querying a parent entity class)

anyone can point me to the right direction to configure my app to right weaving the entity classes?

NOTE: I tested the same query on glassfish (using EJB sessionfacade) and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually The bug was with Tomcat Version, I was using Tomcat 7.0.22 and the bug is fixed with version 7.0.26, so upgrading tomcat server solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that weaving did not occur.  So, you do not have Spring configured correctly.

If you set logging on finest, you can see if EclipseLink performs any weaving.

I don't see anything wrong in your config files, what happens if you don't add the TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader?

It could be that you access your classes before you access your Spring context.  If you do this, then the classes will already be loaded before Spring has a chance to instrument them.

If you cannot get dynamic weaving to work, you can use static weaving, or disable weaving.

Comment: But how can I aceive this? What changes must i make to the configurations?

Comment: See, http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving